# create spark cluster without ssh password-less access

Tags: ssh, apache-spark

How can I setup a spark cluster without setting ssh with password-less access, since the [document](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html#cluster-launch-scripts) mentioned:

> If you do not have a password-less setup, you can set the environment variable SPARK_SSH_FOREGROUND and serially provide a password for each worker.

I'm wondering how to use the SPARK_SSH_FOREGROUND variable??

Comment: @John Titus Jungao for $"${@// /\\ }" see this:
http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/what-is-the-meaning-of-%24-%24%7B%40-%5C%5C-%7D-4175596266/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

environment variable `SPARK_SSH_FOREGROUND` can be set to something like `yes` or `y` to execute `ssh` in the foreground

As you can see in the source code:

https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/2444/commits/1bba8a959ea9ecf21eb0783d3ce302065bf1a154

```
if [ "${SPARK_SSH_FOREGROUND}" = "y" ] || [ "${SPARK_SSH_FOREGROUND}" = "yes" ]; then
ssh $SPARK_SSH_OPTS "$slave" $"${@// /\\ }" \
```